# undefined local variable or method `resource' for for Simple_Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form

I have a users controller with these two methods

```
  def trial_signup
    @user = User.new 
  end 

  def trial_signup_submit
    @user = User.create(params[:user_attributes])
  end
```

my trial_signup.html.erb (simple_form) is in app/views/users

Here is a part of my form

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => users_trial_signup_submit_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

in my routes I added these

```
  get 'users/trial_signup', to: 'users#trial_signup'
  post 'users/trial_signup_submit', to: 'users#trial_signup_submit'
```

my form is getting rendered correctly but its not posting correctly. I want it to post to my actions that I just created.

I have devise installed. I have another signup work flow for registering a user but this is a trial signup so I need to find another way.

Why is the form not being able to find my User model resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user, :url => users_trial_signup_submit_path(@user)) do |f| %>
```

You're trying to render a devise form outside of a devise controller, so you don't have initialized `resource` nor `resource_name` variables.

Probably, you need to change your params in your controller too:

```
def trial_signup_submit
  @user = User.create(params[:user])
end
```

Although I recommend to do something like that:

```
def trial_signup_submit
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    redirect_to <wherever you want>, notice: <your message>
  else
    render :trial_signup
  end
end
```

PS: I think you should change your actions to something like `new_trial` and `create_trial`, if you need something different to defaults `new` and `create`.